# Any alternative to the Alternativa3D engine?

Tags: actionscript, 3d-engine, stage3d

I'm familiar with the Alternativa3D engine
To me it's quite good, but I just wondered about another 3d engine which is able to compete with it.
An engine must correspond to the following requirements:

- must have a good Stage3D support
- be open-source if possible (Alternativa3D is not open-source, it's the major disadvantage)
- must have an adequate documentation and tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few good 3D engines for actionscript. Although I only know of these two that support Stage3D at the moment:

- [Away3D](http://away3d.com) - Stage3D support from version 4.0 upwards and is open-source.
- [Flare3D](http://flare3d.com) - They are not open-source but free to use for non-commercial projects and they also have a really cool website.

Hope this helps.

You may have to compromise somewhat because Stage3D is a new resource so support and uptake especially in free open source engines is going to be scarce. You may need to be more realistic with your constraints and settle for an engine which is not open source or isn't documented as much as you would like.

Comment: Thank you for the Away3D link. The engine is open-source and it's really nice. I've already read about it a bit, but overlooked the moment when they introduced Molehill API support.

Comment: @DmitrySapelnikov It is a new release and is still in alpha although you are free to download and use it. I haven't used it myself personally so that's as much as I know.

Comment: Also, Away3D is now officially supported by Adobe.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.flashsandy.org/

It's documented, and it's open source. I'm not sure how good it is, the samples work...